# How to configure WebMin to accessed via internet (outside my network)

Tags: 16.04, server, webmin

I recently installed WebMin on my server to do some tests, and I'm trying to configure it so it can be possible to be accessed outside my network, but it isn't working. 
I already went to "Webmin Configuration" "IP ACCESS CONTROL" and enabled the option "Allow from all addresses" but it still doesn't work.
I also need to know wich ports do I need to open on my router.

Comment: The default port for webmin is 10000.  There's more information that you may find helpful at http://www.webmin.com/faq.html

Comment: I managed to solve it, the problem was on the portforwarding on my router

Comment: Excellent.  You may want to consider configuring webmin to use a port other than the default due to all the port scanning that goes on.  Also, consider allowing only IP addresses that you will actually use to access webmin to pass though your firewall(s).  Do not expose your webmin port to the entire Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open TCP port 10000 on the router and forward it to the system.

#### Keep in mind this is wildly insecure!

The proper way would be to, instead, set up an SSH tunnel between your remote system and your actual system with Webmin on it, and NOT EXPOSE webmin to the Internet directly.

There are a number of evils in webmin which allow for limitless bruteforcing of the webmin interface with it exposed right to the 'net which makes webmin ***bad*** to expose direct to the Internet.

***UNDER NO CIRCUMSTANCES should you have Webmin directly accessible on the Internet because of the security risk to you, your data, and your network.***  Strongly consider an SSH tunnel via SSH Key Auth and opening the SSH port instead and route traffic over the SSH tunnel to reach webmin instead.

Comment: as an overview I found following article helpful:
https://www.tech-otaku.com/networking/securing-access-to-webmin-through-an-ssh-tunnel/